# JQuery popup issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

IE shows scrollbars when JQuery Dialog pops up. FF doesnt show scrollbars. Whats wrong with IE CSS?

```
<div id="disablebg" style="display: none;overflow:hidden;">
                <uc1:CreateInqGeneral ID="CreateInqGeneral1" runat="server" />
            </div>

 function ShowDialog() {

        $("#disablebg").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            width: "550px"
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: You are asking this wrong. "What is wrong with X" is almost always the wrong start to a question here. Instead "What did I do wrong to have X show my dialogs like this" Show some code, show some pictures. I have seen Fx also show scroll bars on dialogs that had a div that was too wide for the container

Comment: IE has different Box model.Instead of getting frustrated and cursing IE try to use work-arounds for it. You can start by showing us code and screenshots

Comment: If you don't write crappy HTML that sends the browser into quirks mode its box model is correct since at least IE7

Comment: I have added code. This code works fine in Mozilla, but IE shows horizontal & vertical scollbars

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal - IE8 shows scrollbars, IE7 doesn't. I guess it's a jquery UI problem. A workorund would be to modify the css in the dialog's open and close events. Something like $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this to avoid this problem. You can easily modify it to hide the horizontal scrollbar only.

```
function hideScrollBars() {
    var top = $('html').scrollTop();
    var left = $('html').scrollLeft();
    $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $('html').scrollTop(top);
    $('html').scrollLeft(left);
}

function showScrollBars() {
    var top = $('html').scrollTop();
    var left = $('html').scrollLeft();
    $('html').css('overflow', 'auto');
    $('html').scrollTop(top);
    $('html').scrollLeft(left);
}

$.extend($.ui.dialog.prototype.options, {
    bgiframe: true,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function () { hideScrollBars(); },
    close: function () { showScrollBars(); }
});
```

Note: this way I set the open and close events globaly for all dialog instances. If you overwrite the open/close events on specific instances, you have to call the hideScrollBars/showScrollBars functions.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. This trick works fine when i open popup first time but, second time create event doesnt get fired which in turn does not call hideScrollBars() function. How can i do this?

Comment: try to use the open event. I used create, because I always disposed my dialog object on close.